# PHP variables inside an array wrapped in single quotes

Tags: php, arrays, variables, quotes

I am using Amazon API to display dvd and bluray product information on my website. I have the following PHP code that looks up product information based on its ItemID.

```
$movies = file_get_contents('movies.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($movies);

$dvd = $xml->movie->amazon->dvd;
$bluray = $xml->movie->amazon->bluray;

$request = aws_signed_request('co.uk', array(
            'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
            'ItemId' => '$dvd, $bluray',
            'ResponseGroup' => 'Medium, Offers',
            'MerchantId' => 'All'), $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag);
```

I know the following line of code causes the problem:

```
'ItemId' => '$dvd, $bluray'
```

I'm not sure how I can assign two variables inside the array wrapped in single quotes.

If I assign direct values to ItemId, then everything works:

```
$request = aws_signed_request('co.uk', array(
            'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
            'ItemId' => 'B004Q9SZGC, B004Q9T6CO',
            'ResponseGroup' => 'Medium, Offers',
            'MerchantId' => 'All'), $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag);
```

However, I would like to use my `$dvd` and `$bluray` variables to look up ItemId stored in the local XML file (movies.xml) rather than hardcode the actual ItemId value inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can concatenate expressions (e.g. variables and strings) with the `.` sign.

For example:

```
'ItemId' => $dvd.', '.$bluray,
```

Comment: Why would you want to concat?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Boaz. I'm very new to PHP and I'm not sure how I can do that properly. Can you give me an example of how concatenation would work in my particular case?

Comment: @DarylGill To the best of my understanding, that's basically what the the OP is looking to do.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you for your help Boaz.